# Number of balanced-parentheses sequences on $2n$ bits as $n$ grows large

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, computer-science, trees

The motivation to consider the sequences below comes from an [efficient](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0905.0768.pdf) way to represent trees on $n$ nodes using $2n$ bits.

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ be a positive integer. Let us call $s\in\{0,1\}^{2n}$ a *balanced-parentheses (BP)* sequence if $\text{card}\big(s^{-1}(\{0\})\big)=\text{card}\big(s^{-1}(\{1\})\big) = n$ and for all $k\in 2n$ we have $$\text{card}\big(s|_k^{-1}(\{1\})\big) \geq \text{card}\big(s|_k^{-1}(\{0\})\big),$$ where $s|_k$ is the restriction of $s$ to $k = \{0,\ldots,k-1\}$.

If $B_n$ is the number of BP sequences in $\{0,1\}^{2n}$, how does $B_n$ grow as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: These are Dyck words, counted by the famous Catalan numbers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number

Comment: $B_n=\frac1{n+1}\binom{2n}n\sim 4^nn^{-3/2}$.

Comment: Notice the missing $\sqrt{\pi}$ in the denominator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, these are the Catalan numbers. A good starting point is $B_n=\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{2}$, which is established [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#Second_proof). For the asymptotics we can use [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), which gives $B_n=(1+\mathcal O(\frac{1}{n}))\frac{1}{n}\frac{\sqrt{2\pi(2n)}\left(\frac{2n}{e}\right)^{2n}}{2\pi n\left(\frac{n}{e}\right)^{2n}}=(1+\mathcal O(\frac{1}{n}))\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}n^{3/2}}4^{n}$.